# ¿Cómo crear un link para llamar desde Microsoft Teams?

Tags: enlace

Necesito crear links del tipo telto: que hacen llamadas de teléfono, pero que me abra TEAMS para realizar esa llamada.
Los usuarios a los que se llamaría utilizan todos TEAMS.

El link estaría en una intranet del trabajo.

Comment: Podrías utilizar un deeplink https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar la siguiente notación en el `href` con `TEL:`

```
<a href=”TEL:+46890510″>+46890510</a>
```

El usuario debe tener configurado Teams como aplicación por defecto para realizar las llamadas. Si no tiene la aplicación configurada por defecto, le preguntará.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes ver ejemplos en [este sitio](https://www.lync.se/2018/10/set-tel-url-association-for-teams/).